# radical membership and ideal membership

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis

> Consider the ideal $I=(x^3y-x^2y^2,x^3z+z^2yx,x^2-xz)\subset \Bbb Q[x,y,z].$ Is $x\in I?$ Is $x\in \sqrt I?$

I'm assuming a question like this is quite simple and that there is just a method, if possible could someone explain the method or direct me to a similar example of a worked solution.

Comment: Let G = {gt, . . . , gt } be a Groebner basis for an ideal I ⊂ k[x1, . . . , xn]
and let f ∈ k[x1, . . . , xn]. Then f ∈ I if and only if the remainder on division of f by
G is **zero**. To find Groebner basis for an ideal I you can use CoCoA

Comment: interesting, so I would be required to find the G.B for my ideal? would I be looking for a reduced GB? also did you mean the division of $f$ by $G$ should be $1$ and not zero?

Comment: page 82 of "Cox , Little, O'Shea. Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms" . f ∈ I if and only if the remainder on division of f by G is zero

Comment: awesome found the corollary, any chance you can point me to a worked example?

Comment: I can not post a pic as a comment, so i try an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Reposting my comments as an answer, to add a picture of worked example as you want:`

*Cox , Little, O'Shea* 's book *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* page 82, Corollary 2 has:

> Let $G = \{g_t, \cdots, g_t\}$ be a Groebner basis for an ideal $I \subset k[x_1, . . . , x_n]$ and let $f \in k[x_1, . . . , x_n].$ Then $f \in I$ if and only if the remainder on division of $f$ by $G$ is zero.

To find Groebner basis for an ideal $I$ you can use CoCoA. Here is the result for $I$:

[image]

You can see an sketch of what to do, as "Example 1 at page 96" of the book.

---

For 2nd, you can use Proposition 8 (*radical membership algorithm*), page 178 of book:

> Let $k$ be an arbitrary field and let $I = (f_1, . . . , f_s) ⊂ k[x_1, . . . , x_n]$ be an ideal. Then $f \in \sqrt I$ if and only if the constant polynomial $1$ belongs to the ideal $\tilde I = (f_1, . . . , f_s , 1 − y f) ⊂ k[x_1, . . . , x_n, y].$

So we compute a reduced Groebner basis of the ideal $(f_1, . . . , f_s , 1 − y f)$. Then $f \in \sqrt I$ if and only if  the result is $\{1\}.$
In the Picture, below, you can see that $x\in \sqrt I$:

[image]

Comment: Igor Rivin 's answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203995/ideals-of-polynomial-ring-with-complex-number-coefficients/204003#204003) can be helpfull

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem on maple, however for my groebner basis I'm getting the same as yours except $g_3$ and $g_4$ are multiplied by $-1$ ... have I done something wrong? ... also the coefficients aren't there, that might make sense as to why everything is positive

Comment: 1 - $(g_3)=(-g_3)$  2-groebner basis is not unique. (although A **reduced** Gr¨obner basis exists and is uniquely determined )