# Program(s) for expressing a polynomial $f\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ in terms of generators of the ideal $\langle f_1,\cdots,f_r\rangle$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be field ($\mathbb{K}\in \{\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$) and $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ be the polynomials ring over $\mathbb{K}$.

Consider a list of polynomials $\{f_1,\cdots,f_r\}$ and a polynomial $f\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.
Let $\langle f_1,\cdots,f_r\rangle$ be the ideal generated by $\{f_1,\cdots,f_r\}$.

I am currently using wxmaxima. There is a command to find out whether $f\in \langle f_1,\cdots,f_r\rangle$.

> 1. If $f\in \langle f_1,\cdots,f_r\rangle$, I would like to know whether there is any program (prefer open source program) to find out $g_1,\cdots,g_r\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ such that $f=g_1f_1+\cdots+g_rf_r$.
> 2. If we can find out $g_1,\cdots,g_r\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, can we request those $g_1,\cdots,g_r\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ are minimal in the sense that their overall degrees is as small as possible?

According to this post: ([radical membership and ideal membership](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702098/radical-membership-and-ideal-membership)), we can also determine whether $f\in \sqrt{\langle f_1,\cdots,f_r\rangle}$ with the help of Gröbner basis.

> If $f\in \sqrt{\langle f_1,\cdots,f_r\rangle}$, I would like to know whether there is any program (prefer open source program) to find out $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $h_1,\cdots,h_r\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ such that $f^m=h_1f_1+\cdots+h_rf_r$.
>
> If we can find out $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $h_1,\cdots,h_r\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, can we request the following:
> (a) those $h_1,\cdots,h_r\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ are minimal in the sense that their overall degrees is as small as possible?
> (b) m is as small as possible?

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) try `f//(gens I)`.

Comment: `R=QQ[t,x,y]`
`I=ideal((1+t^2)*x-2*t,(1+t^2)*y-(1-t^2))`
`gens gb I -- matrix {{t*y+t-x, x^2+y^2-1, t*x+y-1}}`
`f=x^2+y^2-1`
`f//(gens I) -- matrix {{(1/2)*t*y^2+t*y+(1/2)*x*y+(1/2)*t+(1/2)*x}, {-(1/2)*t*x*y-(1/2)*t*x-(1/2)*x^2+y+1}}`
`((1+t^2)*x-2*t)*((1/2)*t*y^2+t*y+(1/2)*x*y+(1/2)*t+(1/2)*x)+((1+t^2)*y-(1-t^2))*(-(1/2)*t*x*y-(1/2)*t*x-(1/2)*x^2+y+1) -- x^2+y^2-1`

Comment: `R = QQ[u,v,a,b]` `I = ideal (u^2*v-a^3,u*v^2-b^3,u*v-a*b)` `radI=radical I -- ideal(a^2-u*b,v*a-b^2,u*v-a*b)` `f=a^2-u*b ` `f//(gens I) -- 0` `f^2//(gens I) -- matrix {{-a}, {0}, {u*a}}` `g=v*a-b^2` `g//(gens I) -- 0` `g^2//(gens I) -- matrix {{0}, {-2*b}, {2*v*b}}`